# How to concat upcoming variable string until given length in pattern matching?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, elixir

I'm receiving from serialport chopped rfids and I found that pattern matching to new line is not working in this case because after each received data is "\n".
The question is How to concat upcoming strings until state variable string will be equal 16 length? I've tested it in Ruby and joined output string would be `"\u00027A005AFA518B\r\n\u0003"`, I assume that matched string length would be equal 16, eventually I want to extract desired rfid: `7A005AFA518B`. Can I use for this pattern matching?

Current data handler:

```
def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
  [head | _tail] = String.split(data, "\r\n")
  Logger.debug "head " <> head
  Logger.debug "tail #{_tail}"
  {:noreply, [data | state]}
end
```

Log with double check of rfid card:

```
[debug] 7A005
[debug] tail
[debug] AFA518B
[debug] tail

[debug] 7
[debug] tail
[debug] A005AFA518B
[debug] tail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check the size of the string. Since it is hex you can use [byte_size/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.html#byte_size/1) (there is also [String.length/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/String.html#length/1) for unicode strings):

```
def handle_info({:elixir_serial, serial, data}, state) do
  [head | _tail] = String.split(data, "\r\n")
  new_state = state <> data
  case new_state do
    rfid when byte_size(rfid) == 12 ->
      #do something with RFID
      {:noreply, ""}
    _ ->
      {:noreply, new_state}
  end
end
```

Be sure to set the initial state to an empty string in your init function.